# SharePoint 2016 and Exchange 2010, What doesn't Work?

Tags: features, exchange-server

We are planning on deploying SharePoint 2016 but our Exchange Mail Server will still be on Exchange 2010 at least for some time. What SharePoint features will not work with this older mail server?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Site Mailbox is one item that will not work with Exchange 2010.  Exchange Photo Synchronization may be another but not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

It also appears the "Farm Level Exchange Tasks Sync" Farm Feature that Enables the Exchange Sync Timer Job for Work Management Service Application will not work with Exchange 2010.

Comment: It would not work anyway because the Work Management Service Application is no longer available in SP2016